# Knapsack variant with variable values

Tags: computer-science, knapsack-problem

In my line of work, I have encountered the following variant of discrete knapsack and I was wondering if it has already been studied.
E.g. We are given a set of 3 items (A,B,C). The goal is to maximize the value carried for a given weight constraint. The variant has the following additional constraints:

- Step 1: The first item choice is always A.

  If the finite set with A's weights is `W_A = { 3.4 ,10, 12.5}`,
  we pick e.g the value `w=12.5` *once*.
- The choice w of A's weight affects (deterministically) the
  weights and values of B and C. I.e. the weight set `W_B = f(w)` and the value `set V_B = g(w)`. Same for `W_C, V_C`.
- Step 2: We want to maximize the value (for a given total weight) by
  adding items B and C in the knapsack.

Has this been studied before? Is solving it equivalent to performing knapsack once per weight choice in set `W_A` ? (i.e. 3 times in the example above)